# MS Access Mask Credit card numbers

Tags: ms-access

i have table in MS Access that has a column with credit card information. the credit card information can be in any format anywhere in that string. but i need to render it not usable.

example: my card number 2343 25545 454555 2424 exp:12-12

ie. it can be in any format. any location in the string. beginning or end

i need to detect 4 digit sequence and replace or delete.

How to do that? sql, macro,...?

my final goal is to have scheduled daily job that is going to delete / replace some of the CC digits.

Thanks

Comment: Did you know credit cards can have different numbers of digits? Also, this *should* fail any PCI audit.

Comment: Before you even **start** to consider storing this data in an MS Access database, I strongly urge you to [read this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4304748/1324345) about the PCI compliance implications of storing such data.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch also raises a good point; I have 2 cards in my wallet right now that have 14 digits

Comment: **Please do not do this.**

Comment: First, welcome to SO.  Second, it sounds like you are trying to make your own 'encryption' by deleting/replacing some of the digits.  To quote @alroc's link, "Hackers have defeated the security of companies with excellent security. Your security won't be any better."  This can be easily reverse engineered by someone looking at your script.  Also, imagine how it easy it would be to copy & paste this Access DB onto a flash drive and just walk away. I strongly recommend rethinking this project.