# How does Booking.com process credit card info?

Tags: security, payment-gateway, payment, credit-card

Recently I have been reading a lot about online credit card transactions. My project is similar to Booking.com, basically the workflow is something like that:

**1)** User find a hotel

**2)** User clicks on the button to book the hotel, then

**3)** User is redirected to checkout page, where he has to type his credit card

**4)** My system will "collect" his credit card, DO SOMETHING .. and here I'm lost...

I know that I can't save the credit card info, NEVER, so, how I will send it to the hotel? Because the hotel will charge the user, not me.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time searching, reading and learning, I found the solution.

Even discouraged, YES you can store the data, according to this guide, page 14

https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/pci_ssc_quick_guide.pdf

Also this question helped me a lot : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4304748/3350765

Answer (score 0):

The various credit card processors are online.  You initiate transactions with them.  Getting your software and environment certified with them is non-trivial, which is why most vendors outsource that to a service.

Comment: How you interact with the hotel(s) is a whole 'nother ball of wax too.

Comment: In addition, the most popular is Paypal, and [there are benefits to adding it](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/48255/does-adding-paypal-to-a-checkout-increase-conversion-rate). There are a few other good ones out there too though.