# .NET RSA CreateEphemeralKey vs PersistKeyInCsp

Tags: vb.net, rsa

I'm trying to learn more about how RSA functions within .NET and came across this helpful post which suggests that by default keys are stored within Windows:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5845191/1181412

My questions reference the below example code. Assuming the intent is that a one-time key is generated only for the life of the application session.

**Question 1:** In the below structure, does the PersistKeyInCsp flag need to be set to false every time an RSACryptoServiceProvider is created anywhere within the class even if it is accessing the same CspParameters object?

**Question 2:** Does setting the CreateEphemeralKey flag on the CspParameters object supersede the need to use PersistKeyInCsp in this example?

```
Public Class RSACrypto

    Private RSAKey As CspParameters

    Public Sub New(KeySize As Integer)
        MyBase.New()
        RSAKey = New CspParameters
        Using RSA As New RSACryptoServiceProvider(KeySize, RSAKey)
            RSA.PersistKeyInCsp = False
        End Using
    End Sub

    Public Function PublicKey() As Byte()
        Using RSA As New RSACryptoServiceProvider(RSAKey)
            RSA.PersistKeyInCsp = False
            Return RSA.ExportCspBlob(False)
        End Using
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

The `CreateEphemeralKey` flag gets asserted for you if you leave the key container name as `null` in the CspParameters structure (and you don't assert `UseDefaultKeyContainer`).

For a key created with `CreateEphemeralKey` (or implicitly via a `null` name) the `PersistKeyInCsp` property has no meaning or effect.  For a named (persisted) key it causes the key to be deleted from disk when the object gets Disposed or Finalized.  (Note that abnormal termination means the key would never get deleted)

> Question 1: In the below structure, does the PersistKeyInCsp flag need to be set to false every time an RSACryptoServiceProvider is created anywhere within the class even if it is accessing the same CspParameters object?

If the key was persisted then the first time you set `PersistKeyInCsp=false` and called `Dispose()` (directly or via a `using` statement), or let the key get garbage collected and finalized, then subsequent accesses would either fail, or create a different key (depending on if the `UseExistingKey` flag was asserted).  So, it is most correct to say "no, you shouldn't do that".

> Question 2: Does setting the CreateEphemeralKey flag on the CspParameters object supersede the need to use PersistKeyInCsp in this example?

Yes.

**Implicit Question 3**: Why doesn't my code work?

In your constructor you had one of three behaviors, depending on the value of `CspParameters.KeyContainerName` and system state:

- `KeyContainerName == null`:

  - You created an ephemeral key of size `KeySize`. Then discarded it.  No one will ever know what your key was.
- The named key does not exist:

  - You generated a keypair of size `KeySize`, saved it to disk, and deleted it.  No one will ever know what your key was.
- The named key did exist:

  - You opened the keypair (`KeySize` was ignored). Then you deleted it off of disk.  Hope you didn't need it.

In your `PublicKey` method you create either a 1024-bit ephemeral key (if `RSAKey.KeyContainerName == null`) or opened an existing key, or generated a 1024-bit key and persisted it to disk.  Then you export the CAPI blob for the public key, and (if ephemeral) discard the key or (if persisted) delete it off of the system.  (1024-bit-ness is because you used the CspParameters ctor with no keysize value, so the `KeySize` value from the ctor is irrelevant)

What you presumably wanted was to save not the CspParameters, but the actual RSA / RSACryptoServiceProvider object.