# C# RSACryptoServiceProvider. Padding clearance. (Password encryption)

Tags: c#, encoding, hash, passwords, rsa

Could anyone clarify the "whole" story with **Rsa**-related thing. (I guess, that's because of padding or something).

Ok. My general aim is to **encrypt passwords** (one way only) to store in database in **hashed** state.

My approach is:

I create *private/public keys* with this [How to Generate Unique Public and Private Key via RSA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307204/how-to-generate-unique-public-and-private-key-via-rsa) (common) approach.

```
const int PROVIDER_RSA_FULL = 1;
const string CONTAINER_NAME = "KeyContainer";
CspParameters cspParams;
cspParams = new CspParameters(PROVIDER_RSA_FULL);
cspParams.KeyContainerName = CONTAINER_NAME;
cspParams.Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore;
cspParams.ProviderName = "Microsoft Strong Cryptographic Provider";
rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);

string publicPrivateKeyXML = rsa.ToXmlString(true);
string publicOnlyKeyXML = rsa.ToXmlString(false);
// do stuff with keys...
```

and when needed, do this:

```
var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
rsa.FromXmlString(publicOnlyKeyXML);
var valueToEncode = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(rsa.Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(valueToEncode), false)));
// initially that's rsa.Encrypt(...
```

and **every new time** I do the same value encryption, I receive **different values**, which is not suitable to store password in such way (as I don't decrypt it for users' authentication, but just compare hashed value).

Could anyone clarify **the situation** with the encoding stuff?

And also, what are the **common practices** for passwords encoding to hashes these days (.NET/C#).

Thank you!

Comment: Encryption and hashing are two **different** things.  You need to use bcrypt or PBKDFv2.  Do not use RSA.

Comment: I am surely understand meaning of words "hashing" and "encrypting", however, still, the question is on the table.

Comment: Then why are you using an **encryption** algorithm? Encryption is not idempotent.

Comment: The **core** question is **why** those outputs are **different**? (In some conditions I have some code which results the same values (I have some public/private keys pair generated (not by me) which works fine).

Comment: So, generally, that's even not a question about passwords and hashing. That's to understand how is the code works and why the values are different.

Comment: Yes; you're seeing padding.  http://rdist.root.org/2009/10/06/why-rsa-encryption-padding-is-critical/