# Import RSACryptoServiceProvider without persistence

Tags: c#, .net, security, cryptography, rsacryptoserviceprovider

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307204/how-to-generate-unique-public-and-private-key-via-rsa/5845191#5845191) - every time an `RSACryptoServiceProvider` is created it is persisted unless explicitly told not to.

What about `ImportCspBlob`? I have a private key as a byte[], So I use:

```
using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
{
    rsa.ImportCspBlob(keyBlob);
    //rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = false; //Should I add this? Perhaps before the CSP import?
    //Use rsa ...
}
```

Do I need the `PersistKeyInCsp = false;`? Will it be too late because it was already persisted? But using it before the import - won't it affect whatever was the *previous* blob?

Comment: PersistKeyInCsp = false will only disable saving the key in Windows Memeory.

Answer (score 0):

Setting PersistKeyInCsp to false will even remove an existing persisted key, so it does exactly what you're hoping, although as long as your CspParameters don't specify a container name (in this case, you're using the parameterless constructor, so you have not specified a container name), I don't believe it will persist regardless of the value of PersistKeyInCsp.