# How do I ensure that RSACryptoServiceProvider always creates a new key pair?

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, rsa, base-class-library

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1308131/87698) nicely explains how to create a new public/private key pair in .NET:

```
public static void AssignNewKey(){
    RSA rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048); // Generate a new 2048 bit RSA key

    string publicPrivateKeyXML = rsa.ToXmlString(true);
    string publicOnlyKeyXML = rsa.ToXmlString(false);
    // do stuff with keys...
}
```

However, the "Remarks" section in the documentation of [RSACryptoServiceProvider(Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Security_Cryptography_RSACryptoServiceProvider__ctor_System_Int32_) says (emphasis mine):

> **Remarks**
>
> **If no default key is found**, a new key is created. [...]

What is this "default key" and how can I **make sure** that the RSACryptoServiceProvider constructor does not return that "default key" but a new key?

Comment: I would check the store before and after to ensure the behaviour, but got no clue on the remarks. Googling a bit looks like the default key is used [if installed/configured](https://superuser.com/questions/263405/how-do-we-specify-an-ssh-default-identity)

Comment: Looking at the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/utils.cs,462), unless you explicitly state that you want to use it, it will create ephemeral key

Comment: FWIW, you should avoid using RSACryptoServiceProvider.  Use RSA.Create()/RSA.Create(int) when you can, or RSACng if you have to do something fancy on Windows.

Comment: @bartonjs: Then why does [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/cryptographic-signatures) tell me otherwise? (This is a serious question, not a rhetorical one.)

Comment: @Heinzi Tracing that documentation backwards it was [written in 2006](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-3.0/6yxzeb7e(v=vs.85)) (or earlier).  RSACryptoServiceProvider was required until .NET 4.6 (when the RSA base class was fixed to be able to be used without further casting).  There are a lot of docs, and that hasn't gotten cleaned up yet.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but what are you trying to do that you don't need a signed public-key certificate for the new key pair? It seems like you're either deploying a CA infrastructure to make certs on the fly, or you're opening the door to MitM.  Either should be considered carefully in light of the end-use.  (Or an explicitly anonymous protocol, I suppose)

Comment: @bartonjs: Makes sense, thanks.

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b: I am implementing a software licensing system: The private key will be kept secret and used to sign licenses, the public key will be hard-coded in our software and will be used to verify the license. For that, I need a public/private key pair.

Comment: Ah.  So you're really just looking for a single long-lived key-pair in a form easily usable from .NET.  Depending on the stakes, you might want to look at "application hardening" to make sure your licensing system stays in place and in-tact.  If you're just looking to keep honest users honest, it's less important.

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b: Exactly. And since cryptography is easy to get wrong, I read the docs in detail and stop when I don't understand something, hence my question here. Re hardening: Yes, I understand that every locally installed application can be modified to remove any kind of copy protection. As you say, it's mostly about keeping honest users honest.