# Load RSA public key from RSAParams

Tags: c#, cryptography, rsa

I have a requirement to generate RSA key pair in C# and then store public key in the database to be used in JWK format later on.

But I am unable to get the string from the RSAParams.Modulus.

I have tried UTF8,UTF32 and general encoding but still it is not showing.

Here is the code below from MSDN site.

```
try
        {
            // Create a new RSACryptoServiceProvider object.
            using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
            {

                //Export the key information to an RSAParameters object.
                //Pass false to export the public key information or pass
                //true to export public and private key information.
                RSAParameters RSAParams = RSA.ExportParameters(true);

                byte[] modulus = RSAParams.Modulus;
                var str = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(RSAParams.Modulus);
                Console.WriteLine(str);
                Console.ReadKey();

            }
        }
        catch (CryptographicException e)
        {
            //Catch this exception in case the encryption did
            // not succeed.
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
```

Thank you.

Comment: The public key is a combination of `Exponent` and `Modulus`, so you'll have to serialize both. What format do you expect your output to be in?

Comment: Thanks @a-ctor in plain text(string).

Comment: Also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5845191) answer since you are currently storing the generated key on the file system.

Comment: Thank you I ended up using XML to read the value .. not sure it is proper way to do or not.   string publicKeyXML = RSA.ToXmlString(false);

                    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(publicKeyXML);

                    foreach (XElement element in doc.XPathSelectElement("//RSAKeyValue").Descendants())
                    {
                        string value = element.Value;
                    }

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want your output to be base64. Then you can use `Convert.ToBase64String` to convert the `Exponent` and the `Modulus` parts of the RSA key:

```cs
var exponent = Convert.ToBase64String(rsaParams.Modulus);
var modulus = Convert.ToBase64String(rsaParams.Exponent);
```

That is the same thing that your solution in the comments does (see [source code of .ToXmlString](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/rsa.cs,fd15a0bacd426550)) but it does require the detour over XML.